# what's the diff between oracle "initialization parameters" and "session parameters"?

Tags: mysql, oracle

in MySQL, we could you system variable and session variable, those var share the same name and also the some meaning, just one for instance and one only for session.

Is this true for oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INITIALIZATION parameters are stored in the PFILE or SPFILE and are read when the instance starts up.  Most parameters can be modified at any time afterwards, except for the database block size (fixed after the database is created).  (Even though a database is always associated with a particular block size, some versions of ORACLE allow tablespaces to be created with a non-default block size.)

ORACLE initialization parameters are used to control the behavior of the database or the database instance.  They are modified with the ALTER SYSTEM command.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2013.htm

SESSION variables are modified with ALTER SESSION and don't affect other sessions or the behavior of the database or instance.  ALTER SESSION is used to set the language, level of parallelism in the session, ETC.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2012.htm

---

FOR INITIALIZATION PARAMETERS:

Some initialization parameters can be modified only as long as the instance is up and the change is lost after the next restart.  This is referred to as "scope=memory".

Some initialization parameters don't take effect until the next restart.  This is referred to as "scope=spfile".

Some initialization parameters can take effect both immediately and after the next instance restart.  This is referred to as "scope=both".

Answer (score 4):

In a sense, yes. We don't call them SYSTEM variables. We refer to them as INIT params or SESSION Parameters.

See the V$PARAMETER view. It tells you whether a parameter can be modified at the session level. Look at the ISSES_MODIFIABLE and ISSYS_MODIFIABLE fields.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm#REFRN30176

```
select NAME, VALUE, ISSES_MODIFIABLE, ISSYS_MODIFIABLE FROM V$PARAMETER;
```